# How can I encrypt user content on my site so that not even I can access the content?

Tags: encryption

I need to encrypt content in my web application on a per-user basis.

I, the root user, do not want to have access to users' content, period.

How can I make it so users are the only ones with access to their content? Perhaps I can make it so a hash of their login password acts as an encryption and decryption key (then their password is stored one-way hashed in my database, and the encryption/decryption hash is generated from their raw password on login and stored in a local cookie)? But what if they change their password? Then I have to update all their content which could take a lot of processing power.

Is there an encryption method that would provide this, without having to re-encrypt their content if their password changes? Something similar to ecryptfs on Linux, perhaps? Is researching ecryptfs a good place to start?

Is making it so only the user can access their content on my servers (and not even me) even feasible?

Comment: I wonder how hushmail.com does this.

Comment: Here's a white paper on their encrpytion: http://www.hushmail.com/public_documents/Hush%20Encryption%20Engine%20White%20Paper.pdf

Comment: From an email response from Hushmail: Our system is designed in such a way that only with your passphrase can
encrypted email in your account be decrypted. The passphrase itself is
stored in an encrypted hash so even our staff cannot see it. This means
if your mail is encrypted we are unable to read it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Process:**

1. Generate a random secret to encrypt their content.
2. Using their provided password encrypt the random secret from #1.
3. Store their password as a one-way hash (with salt, maybe multi-hash).

**Upon Password change:**

1. Re-generate the value from step #2.
2. Re-generate the hash-cache from step #3.

**Upon Login:**

1. Hash password and check against hash generated in step #3.
2. If password matches - use *actual provided password* to decrypt random secret from #2.
3. Use random secret from #2 to unlock data encrypted in #1.

**Notes:**

- No one can decode the data without knowing the random secret (#1).  Random secret can only be unlocked with user's actual password (#2) (short of brute-force).  User's actual password is only known in one-way hashed form (#3) so you can confirm it's the same, but cannot decode it and recover #2.
- A forgotten password process is not possible (you can regenerate #3, but random key in #2 is now lost as is everything locked in their vault).
- You don't have to re-encrypt everything in step #1 every time they change their password, only the (simple/quick) random secret from #2.
- If you cache their provided password, or the random secret generated at step 1, or their (decrypted) content anywhere you could cause data leaks.

Comment: You generated it, but as long as you don't store it - no.  The only way to figure it out is to have their password to decode the encrypted form from #2.  Or through brute force ;)  You could use a hash from of their password at this step but you *cannot* use the hashed form you store (otherwise yes- you can decode it without knowing their password)

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment because I asked a question I could have answered had I read your post more closely. I like your idea.

Comment: Isn't it possible to generate the random secret client side? This way you really ensure you don't even see the secret

Comment: You could generate it, but it'll have to be passed to the server to setup the container, and known to the server every time someone wants to access the container - so the server will still know it sometimes (no improved security).  Additionally depending on the passing mechanism you add the risk of the random secret being learned by other internet dwellers (not over secure enough TLS, man-in-the middle, etc) during the generation stage.

Comment: @Rudu Is there a possibility to share this encrypted data with another user without sysadmin to be able to decrypt.  I've thought about it and it would need the other user to give the login or something. Because I need the decrypted random secret and encrypt it with other users password. But I can't have the actual other users password. I'm stuck :)

Comment: @TimDinh It is.  A temporary password (T) is created, the new user (B) sends a request to original user (A).  When A approves the share, A decodes #1 and creates a second code of #1 using T T(#1) which is shared back to B.  B uses T to decode T(#1) and then creates B(#1) eliminating T from the system. T is needed during the exchange (decreased security) but learning T will only be useful during the exchange.  Careful remove of cache of T, and T(#1) is critical.  Depending on the content [convergent encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_encryption) may also be beneficial

Comment: Thanks a lot, but (T) must be saved untill User A accepts. So the system knows about it during exchange. So I can read secure content while (T) is saved and user (B) hasn' t logged yet in and has encrypted the random secret with actual password. It seems to me the only way to elimate this is to have both users actually logged in at the same time and to have communicates a shared temporary pw, outside the system?

Comment: The system discovers #1 whenever A logs in (could cache) so I'm not that distinction is that important. However an alternative would be new user encrypts original encrypted password B(A(1)), if the original user accepts he/she removes the password B((1)) when B next logs in access can now be obtained to store 1 (the Double Lock algorithm)

Comment: Ah thanks! Good idea. This means after user B accepts, he'll need to wait for user A to login again and remove the lock. But at least the system now has no way of knowing the secret.

Answer (score -1):

You're spot on that you need to use their password as a key.

I wouldn't monkey with ecryptfs because an encrypted file system isn't the best solution.  You wouldn't want one user's data to be encrypted with the same key that another user used.

When you encrypt the data, you should generate a random string to use as salt.  This prevents someone from using a pre-generated list of hashes to decrypt your data.  It also changes the hash of two people who might use the same password.

When a user changes their password, you'll have to re-encrypt the data and generate a new salt value.  This is the level of security I would expect as a customer, knowing that when I change my password, I'm re-encrypting all of my data to prevent someone from trying to brute force my key.

You can store the salt value in your database unencrypted.

Comment: With eCryptfs, each user's data could be encrypted with their own keys.